# Django Unit tests for forms

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms

Let's assume that I've a form defined as:

```
class NumbersABForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    b = forms.FloatField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['a'] < self.cleaned_data['b']:
            raise ValueError('a < b')
```

I want to define unit test cases for this form as follows:

```
class NumbersABFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_invalid(self):
        try:
            form = NumbersABForm({
                'a': 10.0,
                'b': 5.0
            })
            self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        except ValueError:
            self.assertEqual(form.errors, {'a < b'})
```

Exception is thrown but 'form.errors' is empty. I don't understand how this works. Also, after calling form.is_valid() before which was returning False, calling it again returns True. I don't know how this is possible. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused `ValueError` with `ValidationError`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class NumbersABForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    b = forms.FloatField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['a'] < self.cleaned_data['b']:
            raise ValidationError('a < b')
```

and you should not try to catch it because `is_valid()` should not raise it but instead add an error to the form:

```
class NumbersABFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_invalid(self):
        form = NumbersABForm({
            'a': 10.0,
            'b': 5.0
        })
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        self.assertDictEqual(form.errors, {'__all__': 'a < b'})
```